# Image placeholder size android

Tags: android, image, placeholder

Like Facebook and many other apps, whom have images in a ListView, i want to know how they setup the size of their placeholders exactly of the image to be loaded from server. 
I would be very thankful if you answer my question.

Comment: The only way is to save width and height of the image on server when uploading it. Then you can obtain those values for placeholder while image is loading.

Answer (score 0):

Save the aspect ratio of our images in the database. Then use the Fresco image loader developed by Facebook itself - https://github.com/facebook/fresco .Go through the documentation and learn to use the SimpleDraweeView ImageView class and the placeholder and progressbar on the image cell(do not use wrap_content on the image cell as the developers are against it).It has a method  called

```
simpleDraweeView.setAspectRatio(float);.
```

Simply pass the aspect ratio retrieved from the server to this method and thats it.I recently ran into the same and solved it using this method.Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

Ok. First of all, you need to create adapter for your listview. Here is the tutorial:
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/09/android-listview-with-adapter-example.html

Now, as you can see, you need to create xml for your cell. In that xml, you define sizes and positions of the views.

Comment: No it was not my question. I asked about placeholder size which you will be showing to user while image is loading.

Comment: Using picaso library, you can select your placeholder and it will be stored inside imageview you created in adapter xml.